# How to get both updated document and operation related data while updating a mongodb document?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

Mongodb **findOneAndUpdate** method can be used to return the document and **updateOne** method returns data regarding the operation, such as matchedCount, modifiedCount, etc.

Is there a way to get both the updated document and also the operation related data without using multiple queries?